# Why my PHP script is not running in website

Tags: php, web, filezilla

I am C++ develoer and new with web. I bought web space and DNS, when I try to upload HTML changes they are getting reflected on my website, but when I right any PHP script and upload file no changes are getting updated. I am using FileZilla for FTP. Do I need to follow some directory strucutre?

Comment: If the server has PHP support than you should be able to place .php files anywhere you can place .html files and it will parse them.

Comment: @AlexLunix: Thanks. You solved my problem. Please post it as answer, so I can mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server has PHP support than you should be able to place .php files anywhere you can place .html files and it will parse them.

- Make sure you have PHP support on your server
- Make sure that the files are placed where you place your normal html
  files
- Make sure that the files have an extention that your server is setup
  to use (default is .php)
- Make sure the PHP inside the files is contained in `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Actually I kept extension as .html only. When I rename file as .php, it worked.